Calculate years, months, and days between now and an Excel datetime stamp in the past
How do you calculate years, months, and days between now and an Excel datetime stamp in the past.
For example, cell A1 contains "12/14/2022  12:08:35".
Cell B1 should contain "1 years 5 months 6 days".
We've tried =DATEDIFF, but result is always #NAME or 0.
Is this even possible?

There is no such function called DATEDIFF() it is instead DATEDIF() that said could try using the following: =TRIM(TEXT(DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"y"),"[=1]0 \y\e\a\r;[>1]0 \y\e\a\r\s;;")&TEXT(DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"ym"),"[=1] 0 \m\o\n\t\h;[>1] 0 \m\o\n\t\h\s;;")&TEXT(DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"md"),"[=1] 0 \d\a\y;[>1] 0 \d\a\y\s;;"))

Because Years and Months have variable numbers of days, you can't do this accurately, and DATEDIF will sometimes give strange answers. For example, A1: 31-Dec-2022,   Today: 1-Mar-2024. Result = 1 year, 2 months, -1 days. Note the negative days. If that is not acceptable, use another approach.

@MayukhBhattacharya With A1:12/31/2022 and Today: 3/1/2024 your formula returns 1 year 2 months-. I would think correct answer to be `1 Year, 2 Months, 1 Day``

Definitely, it is possible.
The value in cell A1 is: 12/14/2022 12:08:35
The related formulas are:
=DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"Y") gives 1
=DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"YM") gives 5
=DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"MD") gives 6
Of course, we can combine these formulas in one cell using “&” character.

With A1:12/31/2022 and Today: 3/1/2024 your formulas return 1 | 2 | -1. I would think correct answer to be 1 | 2 | 1.

Ron Rosenfeld
You are right.
Here is a citation from Microsoft website:
"The DATEDIF function may calculate incorrect results under certain scenarios.":
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/datedif-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c
The link above gives the method to workaround "MD" argument issue.
I suggest another method to workaround:
=ABS(DATEDIF(start_date,end_date,"md"))
Where ABS function returns the absolute value.
